# Caching of Static Files in GWT

Tags: java, caching, gwt

Developed application using GWT which contains lot of static files(`javascript,css,images`) which i want to cache for `30` days. I read lot of blogs but didn't get any clue.

*- How to cache static files?
 - What are the possible option to achieve caching (do i need to configure in server or GWT application, here i am using glassfish/payara server for deployment)*

Any idea?
Note: I want do achieve this with minimal code changes, even i read this [Client side caching in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362626/client-side-caching-in-gwt)
but don't want to go with dispatcher approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add something like the [`ExpiresFilter`](https://blogs.oracle.com/cwebster/entry/caching_static_resources_in_glassfish) to your servlet container.

I'm adding the details for the configuration from the link mentioned above just in case the content of the link goes away:

You will need to edit web.xml to add a filter and a filter mapping:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>server.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/\*</url-pattern> <!-- these patterns should match cached resources -->
    <url-pattern>/resources/\*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

If you need a more portable approach for use in different application servers, you might end up writing a generic servlet [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) like I did.

After all that is no big deal as you just have set the `Expires` and `Cache-Control: max-age` headers for [`HttpServletRequests`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) on your given paths.

As a starter, I stumpled upon [this](https://github.com/samaxes/javaee-cache-filter) implementation and [how](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/ab49af84f86fc882933fc12c28e06192a3d351da/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/ExpiresFilter.java) Tomcat does it.

Comment: Thanks sebastain(+1)..what <dispather> will do? is it mandatory?here i m getting one more issue<apha>.cache.html files is giving 404 but i want to cache this file as well

Comment: I think the example for Glassfish uses it to apply the filter also to forwarded requests as `<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>` is the default.

This [site](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnagf/index.html) clarifies it a bit.

I think for your use case you could just leave out both `dispatcher` lines.

But a 404 should not result from the filter, it just tells your browser to not request the file again within a given period of time.